# issue with min-width in IE11 when vertical scrollbar is present

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

**jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/gutd02sq/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="min">
</div>

<br />

<div class="max">
</div>

<br />

<p>This one should be the same width as the one below, there are no long entries in the list</p>
<div class="scroller">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
  <div>six</div>
  <div>seven</div>
  <div>eight</div>
  <div>nine</div>
  <div>ten</div>
</div>

<br />

<p>This one has the expected width, but the one above is wider because of the scrollbar</p>
<div class="scroller">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.min {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.max {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.scroller {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.scroller div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**The problem**

Opening the above jsFiddle in Google Chrome you will see that the two lists are the same width.  However in IE11 the top list is wider because of the vertical scrollbar.

Why is this?  Is there any way to set the min-width of the list in IE11 so that it behaves as Chrome does?